# Content Query Web Part only displays thumbnail images

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, picture-library

I have a default Picture Library with some images in SharePoint 2013 online. I want to display a list of these images using the Content Query Web Part. This is working fine, except for the fact that it gets the Thumbnails by default using the "Thumbnail URL" property. I want to show the full image, yet I can't seem to be able to find the property holding the full image URL.

Does anybody know what Property I should use, or how to get a full list of properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Full Image url is available in property `EncodedAbsUrl`

You can change the webpart property and set this.

Comment: Just adding that this is very useful if you want to append an image rendition which only works on the "pure" url, not the generated thumbnail url.